# C# trigger event for datagridview cell text changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've datagridview with product name quantity and price in column. Column quantity  read-only is false other are set true. User can change quantity in datagridview. Now I want to calculate new total when quantity is changed. I've searched through documentation of datagridview for text changed event but I can't find any possible solution. Any helps, suggestions are welcomed

Comment: Please add some code to better understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal thank you for that link